# How can I mask a portion of an array using Numpy?

Tags: numpy

What I want to do is "mask" a subset of an array of `j` elements, from range `0` to `k`.  Eg. For this array:

```
[0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Masking the first 2 elements it becomes

```
[NaN, NaN, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Does masked_array support this operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [51]: arr=np.ma.array([0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],mask=[True,True,False,False,False])

In [52]: print(arr)
[-- -- 0.3 0.4 0.5]
```

Or, if you already have a numpy array, you could use [np.ma.masked_less_equal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#conversion-operations) (see the link for a variety of other operations for masking particular elements):

```
In [53]: arr=np.array([0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

In [56]: np.ma.masked_less_equal(arr,0.2)
Out[57]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.3 0.4 0.5],
             mask = [ True  True False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Or, if you wish to mask the first two elements:

```
In [67]: arr=np.array([0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

In [68]: arr=np.ma.array(arr,mask=False)

In [69]: arr.mask[:2]=True

In [70]: arr
Out[70]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.3 0.4 0.5],
             mask = [ True  True False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

> > > ma.array([1,2,3,4], mask=[1,1,0,0])
> > >       masked_array(data = [-- -- 3 4],
> > >                    mask = [ True  True False False],
> > >              fill_value = 999999)